# Как с помощью расширения получать то что ввел пользователь и заменять?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Это не в корыстных целях,пользователь будет сам включать эту возможность в определенных моментах.
Нужно любые введеные данные пользователя получать и заменять на то что нужно,как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Расширения? Не совсем понятно как это должно работать

Comment: Chrome Extension

Comment: например номер кошелька и пароль ...будет Вам передавать сам не зная

Comment: Нет,этот проект будет даже не в веб-магазине хрома,а сделан лично для человека. И работать только после включения,т.е нужно как-то мне получить и изменить текст у поля ввода по которому он кликнул и нажал горячую клавишу

Comment: Стандартная задача для [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)'a